# Prisma Issue of managing instances of Prisma Client actively running

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma, prisma2

I'm new to Prisma and Nodejs

I accidentally created lots of instances of Prisma Client that keep displaying the warning of

`warn(prisma-client) There are already 10 instances of Prisma Client actively running.`

Even I tried to delete old files and create a new Prisma, it keep showing the same warning.

I was wondering is there any way to clear the duplicated instances that already actively running?

I found a lot of INFO only about to prevent the situation occur instead of clearing it.

```
Node js version.        : v14.18.2
NPM version.            : 6.14.15
prisma                  : 3.7.0
@prisma/client          : 3.7.0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem is that you are probably creating a `new PrismaClient()` every time you need to use it. The ideal would be to instantiate it once and only use that instance. In the docs they recommend it in this [way](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices#solution)

If you are in a serverless env, you can try this code as well:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      prisma: PrismaClient;
    }
  }
}

let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (!global.prisma) {
  global.prisma = new PrismaClient({
    log: ["info"],
  });
}
prisma = global.prisma;

export default prisma;
```

Comment: For serverless all you need to do is initialize prisma outside of handler according to docs - https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management#prismaclient-in-serverless-environments

Comment: This is all well and good for vanilla implementations, but what is you have a new connections with different middleware ($use) and subscriptions ($on), so a new PrismaClient is required to be created each time?

We use the following middleware implementations: soft-delete, createdBy/updatedBy, and RLS.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are probably creating a `new PrismaClient()`

you can use singleTon pattern to solve it ,(I'm use typescript here !)

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

export class Prisma {
  public static Prisma: PrismaClient;

  static getPrisma() {
    // create a new instance of PrismaClient if one isn't already created
    this.Prisma ||= new PrismaClient();
    return this.Prisma;
  }
}
```